# How to save list values to individual columns in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, save

My table structure is as follows:

```
Id  DimX    pScav   pRail   InjStd
1   Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4
2   Test1   Test2   Test3   Test5
```

I am using entity framework. Column for this table can be added dynamically @runtime by user. So I can not generate my model as static with this number of columns.

My model is as follow:

```
public partial class FullLoadData
{
    public FullLoadData()
    {           
        PerformanceType = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> PerformanceType { get; set; }
}
```

here, in dictionary I have stored all the column names with their values.

Can anyone suggest me, how to save values of it in database?

PK of its i.e. Id is also being used in other class as foreign key.

Comment: Please refer Below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946089/entity-framework-4-poco-with-dictionary

Comment: Dynamic table structure and Entity Framework are mutually exclusive. Use other options, Dapper for example.