# Is there a better way to handle relational table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

That is a simplified example, but I have a `Student` class with a `Relation` enum that describes the relationship between students. I store this data as a `Dictionary<Student, Relation>`:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Student, Relation> Relations { get; set; } = new();
}

public enum Relation
{
    None = 0,
    Friend = 1,
    Relative = 2
}
```

My goal is to create a database with `students` and `students_relations` tables, that would look something like this:

`students`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom |
| 2 | Alice |
| 3 | Bob |

`students_relations`:

| student_id | related_student_id | relation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |

While `Tom` may think about `Bob` as a `Friend`, `Bob` may have a different opinion, so there's no entry like `3/1/1` in the table. But `Relative` relations are different, so there are two entries for `Bob` and `Alice`.

I'm studying the usage of Entity Framework Core to complete this task. I'm well aware, that [dictionary can't be used as property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726966/ef-core-use-a-dictionary-property) with EF Core, so what is the best approach to complete the task?

I've created a `StudentRelations` class for this:

```cs
[PrimaryKey("StudentId", "RelatedStudentId")]
public class StudentRelations
{
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public Student Student { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("RelatedStudentId")]
    public Student RelatedStudent { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public Relation Relation { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my `ApplicationContext` class:

```cs
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; } = null!;

    public DbSet<StudentRelations> StudentRelations { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentRelations>()
                    .HasOne(sr => sr.Student)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Relations);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentRelations>()
                    .HasOne(sr => sr.RelatedStudent);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=students.db")
                      .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();;
    }
}
```

This attempt also requires changing the `Dictionary` in `Student` class to `List<StudentRelations> Relations`.

It does what I need to, but still I'm wondering if I'm doing it the best way possible and if there's a way to map this table to `Dictionary` somehow. Or maybe my database scheme sucks and there's a better way to initialize database, so I won't need a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Seems fine to me... but I don't  get why do you need a dictionary when you are having a List<StudentRelations> ? 
Is the Questsion about how to get a dictionary from the Relations or about the database design or both ?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'd prefer to use only Dictionary without List property and especially additional StudentRelations class. And yes, I'm not sure the database design is good in this case, so I wanted to clear this out too. I just thought, that if Dictionary isn't mapped automatically on EF Core, then it might be something wrong with my vision of db design.

Comment: It seems you want a Many-to-many and join table with payload. Please see [this article in the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-and-join-table-with-payload). EF core doesn't have automatic mapping to and from a dictionary. You would have to set your own convertor up.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. It seems very similar to what I was looking for